# Set up time in ACCESS

Tags: t-sql, ms-access

i have a question about access 2000 or 2003 , can i set up a time for each day that it automatically click on a button in form to perform a query ? is this possible, i think u have to write a VGA code for this ?

Comment: You need to improve your question. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192530.aspx and the Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  To expand on Remou's suggestion:

1. Create an event in Windows Task Scheduler to run at the same time every day.
2. The event will [call](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/command-line-switches-for-access-HA010166605.aspx) a macro in your Access db.
3. The macro will call the procedure behind the button.